# With javascript, how do you get final result URL after 302 redirect on img src?

Tags: javascript, dom

If there is an img tag in a page whose final image it displays comes after a 302 redirect, is there a way with javascript to obtain what that final URL is after the redirect?  Using javascript on img.src just gets the first URL (what's in the page), not what it was redirected to.

Here's a jsfiddle illustration: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Zp4zG/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible. `src` is an attribute and it does not change.

Comment: I'm not expecting .src to change, but wondering if there's any other way to obtain the final URL?

Comment: @jfriend00 not that I know of.

Comment: @jfriend if they are in the same domain you can try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Zp4zG/5/

Comment: @Neal when I run your jsfiddle in Chrome, I get an alert that just says "undefined".

Comment: @jfreind. that is bc in my fiddle they are **not** in the same domain

Comment: you could also do a `(await fetch(url, {method:'head'})).url` these days @Naftali

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, and was already marked answered, but another question that I was trying to answer was marked as a duplicate of this, and I don't see any indication in any of the existing answers that you ***can*** get the true URL via the HTTP header.  A simple example (assuming a single image tag on your page) would be something like this...

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (req.readyState===4) {// && req.status===200) {
        alert("actual url: " + req.responseURL);
    }
}

req.open('GET', $('img').prop('src'), true);
req.send();
```

Comment: How does this help with the 302 redirect on an image?  I'm not following how this is relevant to the question.

Comment: @jfriend This answers the question of how to resolve the source URL if there is a 302.  But in order for this to work, some type of cross-site scripting mechanism has to be in place (CORS, jsonp, etc.).  This won't work for your situation because the image server does not have CORS enabled.  I posted this answer here because it answers this question in addition to one that was marked as a duplicate of this that I was originally trying to answer when it was closed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using third party proxy this can be done. Obviously **not a javascript solution** This one uses the proxy service from *cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com*. Just adding this solution for people who are open to proxies and reluctant to implement this in backend.

Here is a [fork of the original fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zp4zG/22/)

```
$.ajaxPrefilter( function (options) {
  if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
    var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
    options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
    //options.url = "http://cors.corsproxy.io/url=" + options.url;
  }
});

 $.ajax({
   type: 'HEAD', //'GET'
   url:document.getElementById("testImage").src,
   success: function(data, textStatus, request){
        alert(request.getResponseHeader('X-Final-Url'));
   },
   error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(request.getResponseHeader('X-Final-Url'));
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

based on http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Zp4zG, this snippets works in *Firefox 17.0*:

```
alert(document.getElementById("testImage").baseURI)
```

It doesn't work in Chrome. Not tested anything else-

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me in Firefox 17: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/wCXmn/.  The prompt I get is `http://fiddle.jshell.net/jfriend00/wCXmn/show/`, but the actual image path is something more like this: `http://www.smugmug.com/Family/Alaska-Trip-2005/i-v7L6qdv/0/Ti/DSC_0438-Ti.jpg`.

Comment: Maybe you can detail better your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround that I found out. But it works only if the image on the same domain otherwise you will get an empty string:

```
var img = document.getElementById("img");

getSrc(img.getAttribute("src"), function (realSrc) {
    alert("Real src is: " + realSrc);
});

function getSrc(src, cb) {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe"),
        b = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    iframe.src =  src;
    iframe.className = "hidden";
    iframe.onload = function () {
        var val;

        try {
            val = this.contentWindow.location.href;
        } catch (e) {
            val = "";
        }

        if (cb) {
            cb(val);
        }


        b.removeChild(this);
    };

    b.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infous/53Layyhg/1/