# Getting the New Image's URL

Tags: javascript, image

```
var image = new Image()
image.src = "http://www.roblox.com/Thumbs/Asset.ashx?Width=110&Height=110&ImageFormat=png&UserAssetID=1343250665"
image.onload = function(){
    print(this.src)
}
```

When I run this script, this image actually loads: "http://t6ak.roblox.com/65fc2ffcc8aea7ba65a1d1feda173540"

How do I get the new url of the image? I tried this.src, but it just gave me the old url "http://www.roblox.com/Thumbs/Asset.ashx?Width=110&Height=110&ImageFormat=png&UserAssetID=1343250665"

Help?

Comment: You will have to use server side code for this, where you have more control over such requests.

Answer (score 2):

In this special case there is redirection on the server side , so for the client side there is no other `src` ..

Comment: So, is there anyway to actually get the new url of the image from the old url?

Comment: @Luaox i don't think so . note that when you go on the second link you actually see the first `url` path in browser's path bar

Answer (score 2):

Not really. `src` is an attribute and it does not change.

duplicate: [With javascript, how do you get final result URL after 302 redirect on img src?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510674/with-javascript-how-do-you-get-final-result-url-after-302-redirect-on-img-src)

Comment: So, I guess there's no solution?

Comment: always exists a solution. but with javascript no! maybe send url to `PHP` and get redirected url with javascript works!