# jQuery: Get image src after server redirect?

Tags: jquery, redirect

The src of an image is a redirect. How can you grab the URL after the redirect?

HTML:

```
<img src="http://www.be-at.tv/dZUHAA.poster">
```

JS:

```
var img = $("img"),
    realSrc = img.attr("src");

img.after( '<br />img src: ' + realSrc );
```

Test: http://codepen.io/Subfader/pen/grokqP?editors=1010

Comment: Whenever you ask questions you should include already asked questions about that topic like [Can Javascript be used to detect a redirected image SRC (in any popular browser)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082513) or [With javascript, how do you get final result URL after 302 redirect on img src?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510674). Even if there is a solution nowadays you still should mention those questions to shows that you did research.